# How do I login to a GAE app using the User API from a non-browser client?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've built a GAE app using the User API.

I've built some Selenium test apps that login by manipulating the browser to type in the username and password, that works fine.

I'd like to build a command line python app (most likely using the Requests library) to do more performance/scalability testing of some APIs that are behind the login.  How do I login with a custom, non-browser client?

Is it simply a matter of submitting a form to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth while keeping track of all the cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HttpRpcServer` class provided in `google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc` to make authenticated requests against your AppEngine app. It keeps track of the cookies for you.

Comment: Looks very promising, thanks!  I'll accept after I've implemented.

Comment: For example code, you could try looking at Rietveld's upload.py script: http://codereview.appspot.com/static/upload.py